# OData SkipToken Boolean

Tags: c#, .net, odata

While using OData 8 (.NET 6) and the next url an unexpected error occurs:

**Url:**

`http://localhost:5000/odata/test/$filter=TestField eq 1234 &$skiptoken=BooleanField-false,MyField-5`

**Error:**

> The binary operator GreaterThan is not defined for the types
> 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]' and 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]'.

**Error is caused by code line**:

`oDataQueryOptions.ApplyTo`

It seems the skiptoken does not support booleans? Is this a bug of .NET?

Comment: Per the error message, it doesn't (natively) work on booleans because there is no ordering on booleans. `false` isn't considered smaller than `true`. Skipping on a field with only two possible values makes no sense to begin with -- filtering on it, then skipping on another field does, but not paging on the boolean itself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The BooleanField is automatically added to the skiptoken part. Is this due to the fact it is part of the keys of the underlying object? Does a .NET package/ class provide a way to remove the BooleanField in the skiptoken?